# Can I see the response for a page in history

Tags: google-chrome

Earlier today, a server was returning an error that I need to record.  Unfortunately the that, the end-point is working now.  I see the page in chrome history but not the error response.

Is there a way for me to view the errored page from earlier today OR view the response as text?

Thank you!

Comment: Is the page hosted on a server which you have access to?

Comment: @spikey_richie unfortunately not.  3rd party

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your only hope is to locate the page in your browser's cache,
but the error page is unlikely to be there if you have since made
a successful request to this same page, which has naturally replaced
the error page.

So it is too late now.

Comment: sigh... I was afraid that was the case.  Thank you so much